# How to reduce the thickness of the contours?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying OCR using opencv and python. My sample images have really thick alphabets which leads to thick contours when extracted from the canny edge version of the image. Due to thick contours the classifier is not able to classify the alphabet present in the image properly. I want to know if there is any way to reduce the thickness of the contour lines so that it becomes more clear to the classifier.

Comment: Check erosion/dilation or check thresholds for converting image (but text is generally black-and-white, not grayscale, so probably thresholds won't do much).

Comment: Lookup  https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html

Comment: Google for "thinning" / "skeletonization"